# I want to place a dynamic value in a td , in a table there haave a so many td, but I want to place the value in a particular td

Tags: java, html, spring

[image: Here is my table where there have a 6 column, in this 6 column I want to place a dynamic value in Rule Id, Rule Name, then two column fill with static value then parameter and value will be fill with dynamic value, I am getting the value but unable to place according to column.]

Java class for creating rule list

```
public class CompArray {
public ArrayList<Rules> a1= new ArrayList<Rules>();

public CompArray (){
    Rules rul = new Rules();
    rul.setruleId("1001");
    rul.setruleName("khagfkj");
    rul.setParameter("lsrkjglkrs");
    rul.setValue("lskdjfk");

a1.add(rul);

}
public ArrayList<Rules> getRules(){

return a1;
}
```

Controller for rulelist

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/demo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listRules1(ModelMap model) {
CompArray obj1 = new CompArray();
model.addAttribute("listRule1", obj1.a1);
return "hello";
}
```

html table where i want place the dynamic value in a column

```
<c:if test="${not empty listRule1}">
        <table  border ="2">
            <tr>
                <th align="center"><b>Rule ID</b></th>
                <th align="center"><b> Rule Name </b></th>
                <th align="center"><b>Rule Type </b></th>
                <th align="center"><b>Rule Validity </b></th>
                <th align="center"><b>Parameter </b></th>
                <th align="center"><b>Value</b></th>
            </tr>

 <c:forEach items="${listRule1}" var="obj1">
                <tr>
                    <td>${obj1.id}</td>
                    <td>${obj1.details}</td>
                    <td>${obj1.parameter}</td>
                    <td>${obj1.value}</td>

                </tr>                           
            </c:forEach>

   </table></c:if>
```

How to place the dynamic value in a particular column?
Please somebody help me to do this..I have tried many solutions but unable to fix this problem.

Comment: No of th should be equal to number of td. the first th corresponds to first td and so on. If you can tell us what you are getting we may be able to help.

Comment: @sashwat,When i call the servlate the value are appearing in the column in continious manner, i mean Rule_Id & Rule_Name where place in a excat <td> but Parameter & Value where place in a Rule_Type & Rule_Validity, I want place it in a Parameter & Value column

Comment: Add two more tds as below. <td>${obj1.id}</td>
                    <td>${obj1.details}</td><td></td><td></td>
                    <td>${obj1.parameter}</td>
                    <td>${obj1.value}</td>

Comment: @sashwat, in this way i will get the value, but how could i place it in a exact column. please tell me in little bit details sir

Comment: what do you mean about "dynamic value"? If you just want to refresh the values of the tds, use ajax.

Comment: Please understand the html table. No of td and tr should be equal. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp . Table works on concept of 1st td corresponds to 1st tr. 2nd  td corresponds to 2nd tr and so on. I would urge you to read html before trying to generate html.

Comment: @sashwat, thank you sir, i did it, now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two more tds as below.

```
<td>${obj1.id}</td> 
<td>${obj1.details}</td>
<td></td>
<td></td> 
<td>${obj1.parameter}</td> 
<td>${obj1.value}</td>
```